# Binding to an element of a Window ancestor

Tags: wpf, binding

In this code I correctly print the Window Title in the label

```
<Window x:Class="Crono4.Views.MainWindow"
...>
    <DockPanel>
        <Grid ...>
            <RadioButton x:Name="buttonProduct" Content="Product"/>  
            <RadioButton .../>
        </Grid>
        <Grid>
            <Label x:Name="label" Content="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type Window}}, Path=Title}"/>
        </Grid>
    </DockPanel>
</Window>
```

But if I want to refer to the name of the button, this doesn't work:

```
<Label x:Name="label" Content="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type Window}}, Path=buttonProduct.Content}"/>
```

Why?
Thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because `buttonProduct` is not a property of the window and you can only bind to public properties.

You could try using an `ElementName` to bind to the `RadioButton`:

```
<Label x:Name="label" Content="{Binding ElementName=buttonProduct, Path=Content}"/>
```